# How can I dynamically edit a .env file from an npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, dotenv

I've got a `.env` file for a project that I'm working on, I won't reveal the whole file because it contains sensitive data, but, in that file I have an item called 'STATUS'.

> NOTE: This is for a Discord bot,

The 'STATUS' variable looks like this: `STATUS=DEVELOPMENT`

In my code I have a handler that deploys commands to all servers or just my specific server relative to the value of 'STATUS'.
example:
if `STATUS` was equal to `DEVELOPMENT` than it would deploy the commands to the development server and if it was equal to `PRODUCTION` then it would deploy the commands to all of the servers the bot is in.

That code looks something like this:

```js
if (STATUS == "DEVELOPMENT") {
  Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.DEVELOPMENT_GUILD_ID),
    { body: slashCommands },
    console.log(
      chalk.yellow(`Slash Commands • Registered Locally to 
  the development server`)
    );
} else if (STATUS == "PRODUCTION") {
  await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID),
    { body: slashCommands },
    console.log(chalk.yellow("Slash Commands • Registered Globally"))
  );
}
```

In my `package.json` file I would like to have two scripts that control if the commands get pushed to production or development.
example:

```js
"scripts": {
      "prod": "changes the 'STATUS' to 'PRODUCTION' and runs the file",
      "dev": "changes the 'STATUS' to 'DEVELOPMENT' and runs the file"
  },
```

Comment: What is your terminal language? (Bash, Powershell, etc.)

Comment: You _could_ change the `.env` file in an `npm` script, but that's not usually the way `.env` files are meant to be used. If variables are changing per environment, you should set them in the environment, not in a `.env` file used by `dotenv` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a simple utility JS script to do the work:

```js
// status.js
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

// get the first argument passed to this file:
const status = process.argv[3] // the first and second element will always be `node` and `filename.js`, respectively

if(!status) {
  throw new Error("You must supply a status to change to")
}

const envPath = path.join(process.cwd(), ".env") // resolve to the directory calling this script
// parse the environment variable file
let env = fs.readFileSync(envPath)
env = env.split(/\r?\n/g) // optional linefeed character

let prevExists = false
for(let lineNumber in env) {
  if(env[lineNumber].startsWith("STATUS=")) {
    prevExists = true
    env[lineNumber] = `STATUS=${status}`
    break
  }
}
if(!prevExists) env.push(`STATUS=${status}`)

const newEnv = env.join("\n")
fs.writeFileSync(envPath, newEnv)

console.log(`Successfully changed the status to "${status}"`)
```

Then in your `package.json`, you can put the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "prod": "node status.js PRODUCTION && command to deploy server",
  "dev": "node status.js DEVELOPMENT && command to deploy server"
}
```